# Why are some variables in PHP written in uppercase?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

Why does some code in PHP have to be written in uppercase?

For instance:

```
if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
```

Do they work if I write them in lowercase?

Comment: "does this work?" - Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you refer to the function names: Yes, those are case insensitive. You can use `IsSET()`, `IsSeT()`, `isSET()` to your heart's content.

If you refer to the variables `$_GET` etc.: 
No, variable names in PHP [**are case sensitive**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are case-sensitive.

Some you mention have to be written uppercase by convention, the superglobal arrays like _GET, _SESSION et al.